# Template Plugin TinyMCE in magento

Tags: magento, tinymce

I activated the plugin template in TinyMCE on Magento, but I can not insert templates from TinyMCE. In setup.js file (js / mage / adminhtml / wysiwyg / tiny_mce) added the line

```
template_external_list_url : "js/template_list.js",
```

In template_list.js which includes the file in /public_html/js/mage/adminhtml/wysiwyg/tiny_mce/plugins
The magento does not give the option of templates.
What would be the best way to add new templates in wysiwyg respecting the good practice?

Thanks